# How to construct a query to search any field in given page templates?

Tags: content-search, azure-search

I have few page templates defined such as basic page, article page, event page, directory page and each of them has different fields. how do I construct a query in search api to query any item that any of the fields in those templates?

should I do something like following? or is there a better way to do it?

Sitecore is deployed as PaaS solution in Azure using Azure search service not Solr.

```
        void Search(string searchText)
        {
            var indexName = String.Format("sitecore_{0}_index", Sitecore.Context.Database.Name);
            ISearchIndex selectedIndex = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName);
            using (var context = selectedIndex.CreateSearchContext())
            {
                var searchFolder = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/mysite/home");
                var searchResults = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                    .Where(x => (x.TemplateId == Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse(PFPTemplateIDs.ArticlePage)
                        || x.TemplateId == Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse(PFPTemplateIDs.BasicPage))
                    && (x.Fields["field1"].ToString().Contains(searchText)
                        || x.Fields["field2"].ToString().Contains(searchText)
                        || x.Fields["field3"].ToString().Contains(searchText)
                        || x.Fields["field4"].ToString().Contains(searchText)
                    ))
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate)
                    .ToList();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you use computed field that gathers data from all the fields that you're interested in and saves it into a single field? Most of them should be in built-in Sitecore `content` field already.

Comment: in my instance the .Content is null unfortunately - maybe I missed some configuration?

Comment: `Content` is not `stored`, that's why it's null when you try to retrieve it from Solr, but can be used for search as it's indexed.